# React useState() in an AJAX request not ever changing the component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react component that lets you select data to plot (based on a filter and data types), then requests a server with that data, and then uses the server response to create the plot. A simplified version looks like this:

```js
function Trend(props) {
    const [dataTypes, setDataTypes] = useState([]);
    const [selectedFilter, selectFilter] = useState(null);
    const [selectedDataTypes, selectDataTypes] = useState([]);
    const [plotData, setPlotData] = useState([]);
    const [revision, setRevision] = useState(0);

    // Whenever the plot data type or filter changes, we have to re-calculate the plot data
    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedDataTypes.length > 0) {
            client.find('plots/trends/series', {fields: JSON.stringify(selectedDataTypes), filter: selectedFilter})
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('New state!');
                    setPlotData(data.map(datum => datum.toJSON()));
                    setRevision(rev => rev + 1);
                })
        }
    }, [selectedDataTypes, selectedFilter]);

    // When we first create the component, request the data types that could be plotted
    useEffect(() => {
        client.find('data_types')
            .then(resources => {
                setDataTypes(resources.map(resource => resource.get('key')));
            })
    }, []);

    // The template
    return (
        <Plot
            revision={revision}
            data={plotData}
            useResizeHandler={true}
            layout={{
                autosize: true
            }}
            style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            }}
        />
    );

}
```

In particular, the value of `plotData` is an array of [Plotly data series](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/#quick-start), each of which is a complex nested structure. Normally, this consistes of 3 different series, so `plotData = [{}, {}, {}]`

When I update the `selectedFilter`, the AJAX request does get sent, and I can see on my server that new data was returned. In addition, the 'New state!' message is logged. However, the `plotData` state does not change. Even a few seconds after this call, if I check the devtools, I can see that the state hasn't changed.

However, the revision number *does* change. But this is much simpler data, it's an integer, not an array of objects.

Is this related to the fact that I'm changing state within an AJAX response? Or is my `plotData` too complex and React doesn't realise that it's any different to before? This seems quite possible, since **90% of the returned data is the same after I change the filter**. Is the React diffing algorithm unable to tell the difference here?

Comment: Is this right `datum.toJSON()`? It looks like you're converting JSON received from the server to... JSON? Shouldn't the data be parsed _from_ JSON so that plotly can accept it?

Answer (score -1):

One solution is using Axios library:

```
useEffect( () => {
         const callAPI = async () => {
             const res = await Axios.post('plots/trends/series', {
                    params: {fields: JSON.stringify(selectedDataTypes), filter: selectedFilter}
              //just play with response here and update state using hooks
                    }
         }
         if (selectedDataTypes.length > 0) {
             callAPI();
         }   
        }, [selectedDataTypes, selectedFilter]);
```

Comment: You cannot pass async function directly into `useEffect`.

Comment: yes fixing it. I forgot little about that so thanks for updating me.